# Tomcat 7 get resource using new URL and "classpath" string , ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource return null

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, tomcat7

I try to get file resource in tomcat 7 using this code :

```
confFileUrl = new URL("classpath:/conf/plugins/my_app_conf.txt");
        final URL resourceUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(confFileUrl.getPath());
        URLConnection urlc =  resourceUrl.openConnection();
```

The WEB-INF looks like this :

```
WEB-INF/classes/conf/plugins/my_app_conf.txt
```

i need to load it and verify it exist and pass it as URL object to Thired party app ( Accepes only URL object )

But the problem is that :

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(confFileUrl.getPath());
```

result allways null

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: You're mixing file names in your question: gappFileUrl vs confFileUrl.

As you specifically check SystemClassLoader, you won't get your webapp's classloader, thus there's nothing to find.

Use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(name)` to utilize the webapp's classloader (or, to be more precise, the classloader that has loaded the current class. Hopefully it's also from within `WEB-INF/lib` or `WEB-INF/classes`. If it isn't, pick a class that can be found there.

Also note that a web application is not necessarily "exploded" (unzipped) into the file system, but can legitimately be served from a WAR file. Thus, you'll need to use stream-operations, and can't expect any file-based operations to work consistently.

Edit (after your comment): I've never used the `classpath:` component int the URL. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html (emphasis mine):

> The method getResource() returns a URL for the resource. The URL (and its representation) is specific to the implementation and the JVM (that is, the URL obtained in one runtime instance may not work in another). Its protocol is usually specific to the ClassLoader loading the resource. **If the resource does not exist or is not visible due to security considerations, the methods return null.**
>
> If the client code wants to read the contents of the resource as an InputStream, it can apply the openStream() method on the URL. This is common enough to justify adding getResourceAsStream() to Class and ClassLoader. getResourceAsStream() the same as calling getResource().openStream(), except that getResourceAsStream() catches IO exceptions returns a null InputStream.
>
> ...
>
> **The getResource and getResourceAsStream methods find a resource with a given name**. They return null if they do not find a resource with the specified name. The rules for searching for resources associated with a given class are implemented by the class's ClassLoader. The Class methods delegate to ClassLoader methods, after applying a naming convention: if the resource name starts with "/", it is used as is. Otherwise, the name of the package is prepended, after converting all periods (.) to slashes (/).

Based on that: Try loading a resource named `"/conf/plugins/my_app_conf.txt"`. And you don't need to go through the URL construction, but you can pass that name right to getResourceAsStream, e.g. `...getResourceAsStream("/conf/plugins/my_app_conf.txt");`

Comment: Thanks allot , but it still return null after changing to :this.getClass().getResource(confFileUrl.getPath());
my class is in : WEB-INF\classes\com\example\my_tomcat_demo\HelloServlet.class